# FullCalendar Current Event Change callback

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, fullcalendar

I'm using react FullCalendar component and I need to change the background color of an event as it becomes the "CurrentEvent" (when the now indicator is over it).

I'm able to do that when I load the screen, but I also need to do it when the screen is open and the "current event" changes as the time passes.

The way I was thinking about doing that is by using any callback indicating this situation and then changing the style, but I'm not finding any callback that points out this situation.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think fullCalendar has any support for this right now. You'd probably be better to make a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features).

Comment: :( Thanks for the help. I'll see what I can do around here.

Comment: BTW I'm not saying you couldn't write your own timer which tracks the current time, and then looks at fullCalendar to see which event(s) overlap the current time, and then re-render them to change their colour. I'm quite sure you could do that, if you wanted to. But you specifically asked about callbacks etc. in fullCalendar, and you're right that there is no such thing within FullCalendar itself.

Comment: Yes, I thought something more manual like this, even using jquery or something more low level, but I'm not wanting to go this way... Might be the only way though :(